# Switch Between Two Scenes iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, storyboard

This may be impossible, but I'm trying to save the state of my application between scene transitions, but I can't figure out what to do. Currently I love the way that when you have an application running and hit the home button, you can go back to that application just where you left off, but if you transition between scenes (in a storyboard), once you get back to that scene the application state was not saved.

I only have two different scenes that need to be saved (you transition back and forth from one to the other). How can I go about saving a storyboard scenes state without taking up precise memory?

More Detailed: Here is my entire storyboard. You transition back and forth between scenes using the plus toolbar button. On the second scene the user can tap on the table view cells and a real image will fill the image view (See figure 1.2)

[image]
Figure 1.1

In figure 1.2 you see what happens when you tap inside one of the many table view cells (an image view pops up.)

[image]
 Figure 1.2

THE PROBLEM: When you tap a table view cell, which fills an image view (shown in figure 1.2) it works fine if you stay on that scene or even hit the iPhone home button (if you hit the iPhone home button and then reopen the app the scene's state was saved and the image view filled with a simple image still shows just like we left it), but if I transition (using the plus button) back to the first scene, and then use the plus button on the first scene to get back to the second scene the image view that I created (shown in figure 1.2) disappears and the second scene loads without saving the state and image views we filled.

EDIT: I tried using the same view controller for both scenes, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: iOS deallocates these scenes when they are not longer the active view, and seeing as theres isn't a way to save the applications state, you will need to look into saving every bit of data individually using NSUserDefaults, Core Data, or storing into a .plist or SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with MDT.  I believe that writing the data to a file or database is a good solution.  I know this is a lot of code, however it is the most solid solution for memory management and user experience.  Remember, user experience is a top priority.  If they inadvertently loose their work in the app... They could quickly loose interest and uninstall the app.  This is a looser for all.  Good luck!